# How to interpret multi-input/multi-output CNN using SHAP values for regression problems?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, regression, shap

I have a trained CNN which basically takes 4 channels (256x128, velocity fields) and predicts an output with 2 channels(256x128, viscosity fields). In simple terms, it aims to predict viscosity based on the value of velocities in a rectangular domain, which is a regression problem. It has been trained using a supervised learning approach in PyTorch, with input and output datasets that come from CFD simulations.

I now want to interpret the CNN model (U-Net architecture) using SHAP values (or other methods). In the literature, SHAP values have been mostly used for classifiers to interpret CNN models and to study how inputs influence the outputs. How can I approach this problem in my case? Do you know any paper/website where this has been attempted? There is very few documentation on this, and managing to do so will greatly add value to my future publication.

Deep SHAP explainer : https://github.com/slundberg/shap